# Highcharts Tooltip: Introducting a line break into a comma delimited string

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I have a working instance of a chart and the tooltip is displayed fine as well. This is how I set up the series and the tooltip for the series:

```
data.aggCounts.forEach(function(point, i) {
  series[0].data.push({
    name: data.allDates[i],
    tooltipText: data.agSums[i][1],
    y: data.aggCounts[i]
  });
});
```

`data.agSums` string being fed to `tooltipText` looks like this:

```
"item 1: 0, item 2: 3, item 4: 2, ...."
```

I want the items to display in new lines I tried replacing the with /n but that doesn't work. So I introduced a formatter which doesn't seem to do anything either:

```
tooltip: {
  pointFormat: '{point.tooltipText}',
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() {
    let text = this.point.tooltipText
    return text.replace(/,/g, "<br>")
  }
}
```

There is another option to use the original array where the data is taken from and put into a string. This array is part of the data object `@Input data` that is given to my **highcharts** component however when I try to access the data inside options it throws this error:

```
@Input data;

const options: Highcharts.Options = {
  tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() {
      let data = this.data
      //the above line throws: "Potentially invalid reference access to a class field via 'this.' of a nested function", so I don't have access to the original array
    }
  }
}
```

Any Idea how I can either access the data structure inside the formatter function of how I can replace all commas in the string with a `<br>`?

Edit: Even if I access the data inside the formatter I can't use it for a specific point as I can either access the component level variables or the chart instance var. like the **x** and **y** point. Is there a way to access them both if no the only other option is to replace the commas with a newline...

Comment: try flat arrow: formater:()=>{let data=this.data}

Comment: Woah what! why does that work??

Comment: Turns out using that method is not going to work. So back to original replacing commas in string with linebreaks

Comment: OR using the flat arrow I can access component level var. But now I can't fetch the current point (this.point or this.y or this.x or this.point.y) etc. I need to know which point I am on so I can choose the right data for the tooltip

Comment: Hi Haq.H, Your code with linebreaks seems to work correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4yw1vubf/

Comment: Yes, It wasn't working but I shut the application down and when I restarted it was working -_- I guess just one of those things